# linux command for invalid month format replace

Tags: linux, oracle, plsqldeveloper, sql-loader

i have big data file in linux environment.
eg:

```
xxxx,xxxxx,xxxx,xxx,xxx,x,xxx,xxxx,19222222,xxxxx,xxxx,xxx,xxxx
xxxx,xxxx,xxx,xx,xx,xx,xxx,xxxxx,19767714,xxxxxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx,xxx
xxxx,xxxxxx,xxxx,xx,xx,xxxxxx,xxxx,xxxxx,19551734,xxxxx,xxxx,xxx,xxxx
```

this kind of approximatetly 500000 records on file. i need invalid month and date birthdays replace to 00000000 format. please anyone can help to edit this file. Thanks!

Sed command for invalid date format to convert 00000000 format

Comment: Do you have to do it with `sed`? It would be easier in a real programming language.

Comment: Even `awk` would be easier.

Comment: Split the date into year, month, and day variables. Then check if year is outside 01-12 and day is outside 01-31.

Comment: still i try from sed. would you be able to suggest awk command?

Comment: I'm not going to write it for you. It should be simple use of `substr()` to extract those parts of the date field `$9`.

Comment: Are you sure they are supposed to be YYYYMMDD dates, not epoch times in seconds? 19222222 would 1970-08-01 11:30:22, 19767714 1970-08-17 19:01:54, 19551734 1970-08-15 07:02:14... And as you've tagged with with SQL\*Loader, what are you expecting that to do with `00000000`? Anyway, you could maybe use SQL\*Loader functionality to attempt to convert and null on error, at least on recent versions. Or go back to whoever gave you dodgy data. If you really want a Linux solution then you can remove the Oracle-related tags...

Comment: You really should explain what `19222222` is meant to a) be in the first place and in what way it is wrong, and b) how `00000000` is valid.